# Javascript returning wrong time on timezone change

Tags: javascript, nativescript

I'm doing a 'new Date()' in my app and printing it to console to test.

It shows the current time - with correct timezone.

Then I change the timezone on the phone and then resume the app (not close and restart app) - javascript still returns the time based on the old timezone.

Help!

Comment: I tested it on computer: It seems to depend on the browser. Chrome updates the timezone without restarting. Firefox don't update it, open a new Firefox-browser sometimes help.

Comment: It seems like once Javascript session is started - it doesn't re-load the timezone. So if you travel to a new TZ - it still reports time time in the old timezone. If you close app/browser and restart - now it knows about the new TZ. Any command to tell Date class to reload the TZ.

Comment: Look here https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/4022 perhaps it help even it's for node.js